# SOQL: Get most recent amount grouped by a parent and a type

Tags: soql, currency, group-by

Should be simple had it been SQL. But. I would like to get the amount field value that belongs to the most recent month available for that parent and that type.

Data:

```
Parent_Id__c    Type__c    Date__c       Amount__c
1               A          09/01/2016    100.00
1               A          10/01/2016    200.00
1               A          08/01/2016    50.50
1               B          09/01/2016    1000.90
1               B          07/01/2016    1100.40
1               C          05/01/2016    888.20
2               A          09/01/2016    100.40
2               A          10/01/2016    200
2               A          08/01/2016    50
2               B          09/01/2016    1000
2               B          07/01/2016    1100
3               C          05/01/2016    888
```

Desired Output:

```
1 A 200.00
1 B 1000.90
1 C 888.20
2 A 200
2 B 1000
3 C 888
```

What I have so far:

```
select Parent_Id__c, MAX(Date__c), Type__c from Expense__c 
GROUP BY Parent_Id__c, Type__c
ORDER BY Parent_Id__c, Type__c
```

But when I throw in Amount__c currency field in the mix, like so:

```
select Parent_Id__c, MAX(Date__c), Type__c, Amount__c from Expense__c 
GROUP BY Parent_Id__c, Type__c, Amount__c
ORDER BY Parent_Id__c, Type__c
```

...it says "`field 'Amount__c' can not be grouped in a query call`". Sounds like it is not possible to get what I want with pure SOQL ([looked at this also](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000knecAAA)). Can the experts comment/confirm please?

Comment: as per your desired output, use select id...from object order by Date__c.

Comment: Won't work. I am looking for just the most recent record from each parent and type.

Comment: sorry...select id...from object order by Date__c,type desc. will this works

Comment: Sorry, I believe you aren't understanding the question. Perhaps I need to rephrase, but not sure how else. I am looking for 'just the most recent record' 'from each parent and type'. Updated the Desired output in the OP.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot get the specific `Amount__c` given the maximum `Date__c` for your groupings. Not in one go, anyway. I think the path of least resistance would be to scrap the aggregation and just use post-processing.

You could do a mapping of combined key to `Expense__c` record, but it may be easier to just use a `Map<Id, Set<String>>` to track observed values and store the records in a `List<Expense__c` instead. You could use an inner class that looks something like:

```
public class ExpenseSorter
{
    public List<Expense__c> mostRecentExpenses { get; private set; }
    final Map<Id, Set<String>> observedValues;
    public ExpenseSorter()
        mostRecentExpenses = new List<Expense__c>();
        observedValues = new Map<Id, Set<String>>();

        for (Expense__c record : [
            SELECT Parent_Id__c, Date__c, Type__c, Amount__c
            FROM Expense__c ORDER BY Date__c DESC Parent_Id__c
        ]){
            if (!observedValues.containsKey(record.Parent_Id__c))
                observedValues.put(record.Parent_Id__c, new Set<String>{ record.Type__c });
            else if (!observedValues.get(record.Parent_Id__c).contains(record.Type__c))
                observedValues.get(record.Parent_Id__c).add(record.Type__c);
            else
                continue;
            mostRecentExpenses.add(record);
        }
    }
}
```

Or you could remove the query and accept the `List<Expense__c>` as a constructor parameter for added flexibility. The above is just an idea to give you the general outline of how you can solve your problem.

Comment: Unbelievable. This is like killing an ant with a bazooka. Miss SQL. But thanks for the tip!

Comment: @Kal You could reduce the number of records queried by adding more onto it, but I'm not sure that would be to your taste either. It's a platform with many limitations, but if you spend long enough on it, you learn to love it.